# vim and Ultisnips

Tags: vim, ultisnips

I'm trying to understand how Ultisnips works (very few documentation when you're a beginner like me) and in the `all.snippets` code there a function that returns `vim.eval("&comments")`

So I'm trying to guess how this works, and if I try:

```
:let g=eval("&comments")
:echo g
```

I get this: `s1:/*,mb:*,ex:*/,://,b:#,:%,:XCOMM,n:>,fb:-`
*when i'm in the snippet file*.

If I open up a an empy Php file and try the previous code I get `s:<!--,m:    ,e:-->`

I want to have the classical comment like this `/*  */` configured to that I could call the sample snippet "`box`" (it works but adds `<!-- -->` = HTML comment delimiters instead of actual Php comment delimiters).

How can I guess *when* it's assigned, and how to change `<!-- -->` to `/*  */`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `commentstring` instead of `comments`. The former is set to the correct valus in php.

Comment: According to vim help: `comments` is a comma separated list of strings that can start a comment line, whereas `commentstring` is a *template* for a comment. So they are not made for the same goal.